# Objective-C: Get the number of calendar days between two dates

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I just don't get the correct result...so depending on the timezone I want the calendar day difference between two dates. So if one starts at 23:00 on day 1 and ends on 14:00 on day 2 it should return 1. Now my method returns 0, why? Because it's less than 24 hours? Example:

MY Nslog:

```
CheckForPictures departure date: Tue Jan 28 23:10:00 2020 destinationDate: Wed Jan 29 09:30:00 2020 in timeZone:Europe/Zurich and get a day difference: 0
```

(Computer has also timezone Zurich, so it is local time)

My Method:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                    fromDate:self.departureTime
                                                      toDate:self.destinationTime
                                                     options:0];

NSLog(@"CheckForPictures departure date: %@ destinationDate: %@ in timeZone:%@ and get a day difference: %ld", self.departureTime, self.destinationTime, timeZone.name, components.day);

return components.day;
```

And this code returns 0 and logs above log...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking `NSCalendar` the wrong question. You want to know if the arrival date is different than the departure date, but you're asking for the number of *days* between arrival and departure. A date change could happen even if the difference in time is only a few minutes. "A few minutes" rounds to "0 days" if you ask how many days have passed.

You actually want to know if the *date* has changed. I think I would be doing something like getting the day of the month for each date and comparing that. Since no months have 1 day, I would think that would work.

Comment: Ok so my first question: NSCalendarUnitDay then calculates in 24 hour differences? I assume so and I also thought about your solution. But let's say the difference is more than one day and month overlapping: How would I calculate that? For example 29th of February 23:00 - March 2 01:00, I would like a result of 2 in that case

Answer (score 0):

With Craigs input I came up with this solution:

```
- (NSInteger)calendarDaysBetweenDepartureAndArrivalTimeForTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];

    NSDateComponents *departureComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:self.departureTime];
    NSDateComponents *destinationComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:self.destinationTime];

    NSInteger difference = destinationComponents.day - departureComponents.day;
    if(difference < 0){
        //Month overlapping
        NSRange range = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:self.departureTime];
        difference = range.length - departureComponents.day + departureComponents.day;
    }

    NSLog(@"CheckForPictures departure date: %@ destinationDate: %@ in timeZone:%@ and get a day difference: %ld", self.departureTime, self.destinationTime, timeZone.name, difference);

    return difference;
}
```